# Limit that fail to exist

Tags: limits, soft-question, infinity

Does a limit that equals to infinity considered to exist ?? am confused !!

for Example 1/(x-2)--> when evaluating the limit at 2  the result is 1/0 which is infinity
while after looking at the graph the left hand limit equals -inf while right hand limit 
equals +inf does the one sided limits exists ??

pls an expert discuss existence of limits for my question and example because am confused

thanx

Comment: It is better to never ever write $\frac{1}{0}$. For $x$ close to $2$ but a little larger than $2$, the quantity $\frac{1}{x-2}$ is very large positive. For $x$ close to $2$ but smaller than $2$, the quantity is very large negative. So the limit as $x\to 2$ does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit exists if the values approach some real number.  If the values are getting bigger and bigger the limit doesn't exist.  There are other ways the limit could not exist.  Saying the limit is infinity is being more specific about how the limit fails to exist.

Also, saying "the result is 1/0" causes many math folks pain.  You could say the denominator is going to zero, so the whole thing is going to infinity.  Or if you don't want to say that much, just say the limit is infinity.

Comment: do you mean that both one sided limits fail to exist so am not going to check for their equality, that's why the two sided limit fail to exist ??

Comment: I didn't say anything about one sided limits but what you said is true.

Comment: thanks i was just double checking with u :)

Comment: Does this means infinity is the case "undounded behavior"...thnx

Answer (score 0):

If we consider the real number or complex number system then the limit does not exist. But if we include ∞ with that system, which is called extended real number or extended complex number system, then obviously we have to say that the limit exists.

Comment: you mean each one of the two sided limit exists??? but what about the two sided limit in case we have one is +inf  and the other one DIFFERS since it's -inf ??

Comment: There are two methods for extending real number system. One is considering +inf and -inf. Then the limit does not exist. But if you take only inf (not +inf & -inf) then the limit exists. The method of extension is very much like the method of extension of complex numbers via stereographic projection. Here you have to consider a circle in place of the sphere.